# How do I get today's date in C# in mm/dd/yyyy format?

Tags: c#, date

How do I get today's date in C# in mm/dd/yyyy format?

I need to set a string variable to today's date (preferably without the year), but there's got to be a better way than building it month-/-day one piece at a time.

BTW: I'm in the US so M/dd would be correct, e.g. September 11th is 9/11.

*Note: an answer from kronoz came in that discussed internationalization, and I thought it was awesome enough to mention since I can't make it an 'accepted' answer as well.*

[kronoz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32747/how-do-i-get-todays-date-in-c-in-8282008-format#32819)

Comment: M/dd would show Jan 1 as 1/01.  Do you want 1/01 or just 1/1?

Answer (score 228, accepted):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: hh:mm:ss gives the time.   DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss");

Answer (score 23):

Not to be horribly pedantic, but if you are internationalising the code it might be more useful to have the facility to get the short date for a given culture, e.g.:-

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

...

var currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
try {
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-us");
  string shortDateString = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
  // Do something with shortDateString...
} finally {
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = currentCulture;
}
```

Though clearly the "m/dd/yyyy" approach is considerably neater!!

Answer (score 17):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 9):

```
DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString()
```

is culture specific.

It is best to stick with:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("d/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want it without the year:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/DD");
```

DateTime.ToString() has a lot of cool format strings:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326721.aspx

Answer (score 8):

```
string today = DateTime.Today.ToString("M/d");
```

Answer (score 5):

```
DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString()
```

I think this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 4):

Or without the year:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("M/dd")
```