# Get current date in personalized format in c#

Tags: c#, date, format

I would like to know if there is a way to get the current date in the following format :

```
YYYY.MM.DD
```

I know that I can get the current date, and then manipulate it to get the desired format, but I was wondering if there is a pattern solution to specify my own format and so directly getting a string like this :

```
"2014.06.10"
```

Comment: You can use ANYTHING in the ToString() method to format the date as you like: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` should be enough.

Comment: The default return format is controlled by the CultureInfo. You can start here to learn about creating a custom culture http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172469(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks, It's working, but the solution proposed by alykins is also working. Being a little curious, I would like to know which solution is the better and also the meaning of CultureInfo.InvariantCulture?

Comment: I'd love to know why I got down voted as it's a perfectly acceptable answer. It might not be as elegant as Habib but it is an answer that is correct none-the-less

Comment: Please make a basic effort to find the answer before asking a duplicate. This question has been asked and answered hundreds of times, probably dozens on StackOverflow alone. You'd find the solution if you'd just bother to look for it. Even reading the documentation would tell you the answer. Which solution is "better" is a matter of opinion. The meaning of `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` can *also* be answered by reading the documentation/Googling.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get today's date in C# in 8/28/2008 format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32747/how-do-i-get-todays-date-in-c-sharp-in-8-28-2008-format)

Comment: Ok, I will make better search efforts before asking a question.

Answer (score 2):

```
string dateFormatted = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string.Format() method and reference this link [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The {#} represents the argument being passed and the {#:yyyy} is a way of formatting to grab just the year in format of yyyy. Same for MM and dd. Worth noting is that mm is minutes and MM is months which may be confusing as day and year are also lower case.

```
string.Format("{0:yyyy}.{0:MM}.{0:dd}", DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation of op's problem and why this works. In response to your comment, if you're not willing to provide a detailed answer, leave a comment next time and you won't get downvoted.

Comment: Added some clarification.